# The ConnectionString property has not been initialized bug

Tags: c#, app-config

ok so i seem to be getting an annoying bug that i hope you can help me with.

I am using winforms and on an application set up form, I provide functionality to change the connection string. When the different parts of the connection string is changed and the user leaves the textbox, it writes the information to the app.config. This all works like a charm.

I have a button to test the connection, so when this is pressed after the connection string has been changed anytime while the form is still open, I hit an error:

```
The ConnectionString property has not been initialized
```

to make this a bit more complex, when i close and reopen the application, the same form is now able to make the connection and all works smoothly. Its almost as if the Config is locking itself from being queried after a change is made.

Is there something i need to do in between making changes to the app.config and attempting to open up a connection using the stored connection string.

here is my code to change the app.config:

```
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
     config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["myconnstr"].ConnectionString = textboxCS.Text;
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

here is my code to test the connection:

```
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        string constr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnstr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                connection.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Successful Connection");
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                ee.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show("Failed Connection");
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Have tried with single word key like `ConStr` instead of `Clock_Card.Properties.Settings.HH_ClockCardConnectionString`

Comment: Are you getting the message "Failed Connection"?  The using statement is outside the exception handler so I don't think you are actually getting to the connectionOpen.  The constructor is failing which I think means a connection is already open.

Comment: @jdweng ok so, while debugging, i can step to  connection.Open(); but thats where it hits the exception

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i have edited the code to reflect the correct connection string name

Comment: @StuartBlack Is this code is in the different class library?

Comment: Is the method ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration() opening the connection and then you are trying to open the connection a 2nd time?

Comment: Did you debug the code? What value you are getting in `constr` when you are testing the connection? What is the value of `ee.Message`?

Comment: I found the error thanks to you guys... this :

string constr = 
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnstr"].ConnectionString;

needed to  be replaced with:

string constr = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["myconnstr"].ConnectionString;

Comment: I need sleep...

Comment: Note: you don't need the `finally` block: when the code exits the `using` block of the connection, it will Dispose the connection, which calls Close. Similarly you don't want to call Close in the `try`: for example there is a route through the code where Close would have been called twice.

Comment: @Richardissimo thanks, yeah i usually dont use the try catch in conjunction with the using, but, i decided to put it in temporarily during debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this :

```
string constr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnstr"].ConnectionString;
```

needed to be replaced with:

```
string constr = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["myconnstr"].ConnectionString;
```

The problem was that it was trying to open ConfigurationManager twice

Thanks for all the help guys